# Is it possible to prevent function override in a C shared library?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, overriding, shared-libraries

I am developing a shared library on Linux in C using GCC. I noticed that any function in the shared library can be overridden by redefining it in the main application. Is there a way to prevent specific functions from being overridden in a shared library?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to export that function to the world, make it `static`

```
static void a() {
}
void b() {
    a();
}
```

the main application will have no way to directly call `a`, but maybe you don't need that.

If you want to also export that function the the world, you could do:

```
static void real_a() {
   /* the actual implementation */
}
void a() { /* wrapper for export */
    real_a();
}
void b() { /* your library code has to call the real function */
    ...
    real_a();
}
```

The main application can still override `a`, but that does not influence the library code, which is calling `real_a` internally.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you